# Using an instance of PDO class as global variable inside 'query' methods

Tags: php

I have one PHP file named database.php:

```
 try {
     $connection= new PDO(DB_DNS, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
     $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(Exception $e) {
     echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
     die();
}
```

and I have a user.php with class `Users`:

```
require_once(__DIR__."/../includes/config.php");
require_once(__DIR__."/../includes/database.php");

class User
{
    public function pronadjiSveUsere() {
        global $connection;
        $upit = $konekcija->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
        $rezultat_upita = $upit->execute();
        return $rezultat_upita;
    }

    public function find_by_id($id = 0) {
        try {
            global $connection;
            $upit = $konekcija->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
            $rezultat_upita = $upit->execute(array($id));
            return $rezultat_upita->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

So, you can see that there is a global `$connection` in each of the methods. Is this bad and why? If so, what would you do, as parameter passing, or with a constructor?

Comment: So, I always should do in this way: `class User { public function find_by_id($id, $connection) { ...`, right?

Comment: No, I'd advice against that because: 1) There's no type-hint (I can pass an int as second argument, but you need `$connection` to be a `PDO` instance). 2) You don't want the caller to have to pass a DB connection for each method. Dependency Injection is what you really ought to be going for 3) `PDO::prepare` returns an instance of `PDOStatement`, which is reusable, your code doesn't take advantage of that fact. 4) `try {} catch() { die;}` is code smell: catch an exception if you know how to handle that exceptional case, if not: let the exception propagate to code that does

Comment: Posted a hasty review of your code there. Leave a comment if something is a tad unclear there

Answer (score 2):

Use global scope for as little as possible. EVER.

Explicitly passing the connection it into the method is always the safe and happy.  It allows for better testing by adhering to dependancy inversion principles.

You could also do it inside of the constructor if the the connection doesn't change during the life of the object, but I'm not a fan of this--I'd prefer a `intitial()` method to be called after instantiation or explicitly setting it with a `set_connection()` method.

Comment: So, I always should do in this way: `class User { public function find_by_id($id, $connection) { ...`, right?

Comment: I'd put the connection as the first argument and specify the type PDO as in one of your comments on the OP

Comment: @ray: it's far from fine: there's no type-hint. Each call will call `PDO::prepare`, creating the exact same prepared statement (not what you want) and `try-catch-die` is code smell, as is a method that `echo`'s. Methods return, templates take care of output

Comment: Read my comment about the above yours about adding the type hint.   The question is not about general improving the code overall, but about specifcally if they should be passing in or using a global connection.  I think my word choice of 'method is fine' is poor as I was not referering to his classes method, but his suggestion of his plan to use the passing it into his method.  I'm deleteing as my following comment is more clear.